# Can Linux Mint v20.3 send 1080P display output signal over CAT6 cable?

Tags: networking, linux-mint, hdmi

I got an Asus PN51, Ryzen mini-ITX PC running Linux Mint v20.3. It is connected to my living room LG SmartTV HDMI port which allows me to see YT videos without ads. I would now like to have the same functionality for my LG SmartTV located in my bedroom. However, it will take a 60 foot HDMI cable to connect the display output from my living room PC to my bedroom LG SmartTV. Obviously that is not feasible due to how HDMI cables do not support such long distances. Another option is I buy a second $700 Asus PN51 for my bedroom LG SmartTV. But I want to avoid spending another $700 for a second pc to connect to my Bedroom LG SmartTV HDMI port.

Therefore, how can I pipe my living room PC display output via CAT 6 cable so it feeds a 1080P display output signal to my bedroom LG SmartTV? I have all devices mentioned connected to my NetGear Router and a powerful IR remote that allows me to control my PC no matter where I am at in my house. Does Linux Mint v20.3 have a special IP video forwarding configuration I can use to make this happen?

Any advice will be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a Linux-specific question. It does not belong on this site.

Comment: you're not trying to "send 1080p display signal over CAT6 cable"; you're trying to send them through an Ethernet network! That's a different problem! Just because something uses a cable doesn't mean whatever you put into the cable will work with the switch at the other end :)

Comment: so, no, uncompressed, this cannot work, simply because you have gigabit Ethernet (which does 1 Gb/s), and 1080p with three color channels a 8 bit and 30 frames per second is (1920×1080)px/frame × 30 frames/second × 3 channels/pixel × 8 bit/channel > 10⁹ bit/s.

Comment: compressed: sure. You could have your mini PC simply share its screen over network; there's different solutions for that. However, you'll need some kind of computer to open that stream. A modern Raspberry Pi would be fast enough – but it would also be fast enough to play youtube.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need a HDMI to Ethernet adapter, such as [this one from Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07WFLHTKK)

If that link doesn't work, just search "HDMI Extender 1080p@60Hz, 3D, Over Single Cat5e/Cat6/Cat 7".

Comment: Read closely: they want to connect through a switch /router! Although the title of your product claims it, this is *not* an ethernet device (it can't be, 1080p RGB 30fps wouldn't fit through 1 Gb/s ethernet).

Comment: Not my product. Was just an example. Guess the way I worded that made it appear that way. What OP wants done is possible with such a device. We use them at work to share a laptop's screen with multiple televisions. All over Cat5. Nothing goes through any networking device. Just a receiver to split the HDMI stream.

Comment: No, it's not possibly done with such a device! You **cannot** physically fit the data rate of a 1080p video at acceptable framerates through ethernet. And he needs ethernet.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).